# non-complete problem collapsing to a lower complexity class complete problem

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

Let us say that there is a NP problem that is not a complete problem. And let us assume that someone found that the problem is in fact P-complete problem.

Does this imply P=NP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a problem in NP, which is proven to be not $\text{NP}$-Complete, then this implies $\text{P} \neq {NP}$.

This is because, if $\text{P} = \text{NP}$, then all (non-trivial) problems are trivially $\text{NP}$-Complete: reduce $3$-$\text{SAT}$ by solving $3$-$\text{SAT}$ as part of the reduction.

Also, when it comes to completeness, $\text{P}$-Complete and $\text{NP}$-Complete are entirely different notions.  Trying to relate the two seems a bit strange. Unfortunately the term "Completness" is overloaded, and the confusion which students face is understandable.

When we talk about Completeness, we have a specific constraint on the reductions we can use, which *depends* on the class whose completeness we are talking about. The reductions we choose for one class need not be the same as for other  classes.

Usually, we define $\text{NP}$-Completness to use polynomial time reductions. There are other definitions too, look up Karp vs Cook on the web.

Usually, $\text{P}$-Completeness uses LogSpace reductions. Polynomial time reductions make no sense to define $\text{P}$-Completness: every problem would be $\text{P}$-Complete trivially.

There are problems which have been proven to be $\text{P}$-Complete under LogSpace reductions and that has no bearing on the $\text{P} = \text{NP}$ problem.

For instance, even if we managed to show that $\text{P} = \text{NP}$, it does not mean every $\text{NP}$-Complete problem is $\text{P}$-Complete. The question of whether LogSpace = P would still need to be resolved.

Comment: In the last paragraph, if P=NP, then it _does_ mean that every P-complete problem under log-space reducibility is NP-complete under polynomial-time reducibility.  I think that you meant to write the opposite: even if P=NP, it does not mean that every NP-complete problem under polynomial-time reducibility is P-complete under log-space reducibility.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Right. I meant it that way. In fact a previous revision had it that way and I changed it for some reason (it does not show up though). Corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with very rough and informal descriptions of P and NP.

P is the set of decision problems that can be solved "quickly".

NP is the set of problems for which a proposed solution can be checked "quickly". If I tell you that $x$ is a solution to your problem, then you can quickly check whether or not $x$ really is a solution.

In particular, all problems in P are also in NP. Intuitively, it is easier to check whether $x$ is a solution than to actually find a solution. So all P-complete problems are automatically in NP. Finding a NP-problem which is P-complete is the same as finding a P-complete problem. It does not tell us anything about whether $P=NP$ or $P \neq NP$.

Thus finding a P-complete problem (like the ones on [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete)) does not tell us anything about P versus NP.